# Reduced my SQL by 40% but it runs 60 times slower?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have SQL generated by `JPA`, which in the worst case had 1250 lines.

The structure of my query was 20 sub-queries nested inside the `WHERE` statement of a query. This query ran in 0.015 seconds.

I tried to optimize my query as I noticed I had reused a lot of joins in the sub-queries (e.g where two sub-queries only differed by their `WHERE` statement). This reduced the SQL down to 750 lines and to 12 sub-queries, but for some reason it took 0.9 seconds to run.

Is there anything to explain this? Might my attempt to make the query run faster actually run faster when there is much more data available?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have indexes in the fields included in the where clause?

Comment: This is serious magic. How about providing your sql code, table structures and query plans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited information provided in the question I can only speculate as to exactly why the execution time increases in your specific case, but the long and the short of it is that less code does not equal faster queries.

One of the main reasons "simplifying" queries can result in longer execution times is that the simplification means indexes are no longer used because while the query may appear more simple to read, you are actually asking the optimiser to do something more complicated.

Imagine this simple schema:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, A INT);
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, A INT, B INT);

CREATE INDEX IX_T2_A ON T2 (A);
CREATE INDEX IX_T2_B ON T2 (B);
```

Now, supposing I have the following query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(T1.ID)
FROM    T1
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  ID
            FROM    T2
            WHERE   A IN (1, 10)
            UNION 
            SELECT  ID
            FROM    T2
            WHERE   B IN (1, 10)
        ) T2
            ON t2.ID = t1.ID;
```

You might think, that this can be "simplified" to remove the `UNION` as follows:

```
SELECT  COUNT(T1.ID)
FROM    T1
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  ID
            FROM    T2
            WHERE   A IN (1, 10)
            OR      B IN (1, 10)
        ) T2
            ON t2.ID = t1.ID;
```

**HOWEVER**, by combining your criteria you have ensured that neither index (on `T2.A` or `T2.B`) will be used, because the optimiser is trying to perform both at once. So instead of using the two indexes you have in place, a full table scan will be performed, and depending on the distrubution of your data this can be much more costly.

This is confirmed when running `EXPLAIN`:

```
ID      SELECT_TYPE     TABLE       TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY     KEY_LEN     REF     ROWS    FILTERED    EXTRA
1       PRIMARY         <derived2>  system  (null)          (null)  (null)      (null)  1       100     
1       PRIMARY         T1          const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4       const   1       100         Using index
2       DERIVED         T2          index   IX_T2_A         IX_T2_A     5       (null)  1       100         Using where; Using index
3       UNION           T2          index   IX_T2_B         IX_T2_B     5       (null)  1       100         Using where; Using index
(null)  UNION RESULT    <union2,3>  ALL         (null)  (null)      (null)  (null)  (null)      (null)  


ID      SELECT_TYPE TABLE       TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY     KEY_LEN     REF     ROWS    FILTERED    EXTRA
1       PRIMARY     <derived2>  system  (null)          (null)  (null)      (null)  1       100     
1       PRIMARY     T1          const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4           const   1       100     Using index
2       DERIVED     T2          ALL     IX_T2_A,IX_T2_B (null)  (null)      (null)  1       100     Using where
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52268/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those extra lines created much smaller tables *(or selected less data)* than the ones you have atm, hence you could compare tables *(data)* more quickly. However now, as you have reduced the number of smaller tables and presumably increased the size of the bigger ones, the queries has to page through larger tables *(more data)* when you run a specific query, therefore they take more time.

More data to compare = More processing time

Comment: Yep thanks this was the issue. It turns out that while some sub-queries shared some joins, the way I was amalgamating them involved joining on a new table(s) so that the new sub-query could have all the joins it needed. This meant that each WHERE statement in the new query had to page through a larger table than it would have had to previously.

Answer (score 0):

If the query ran that fast, then it is not processing very many rows.

In all likelihood, the joins were being processed using indexes.  The engine could just load the indexes in memory and process the queries -- possibly never even touching the original data.

When you materialize the joins without the `where` clauses, a few things happen:

1. You know have the overhead of reading and writing additional data;
2. The amount of data being processed may be larger than in any of the subqueries;
3. Additional optimizations -- that could potentially even eliminate much of the processing -- do not take place.